# Plotly.js returns unexpected data when 'plotly_click' event is fired

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

- https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#click-event
- https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/#click-event-data
- https://community.plot.ly/t/documentation-on-plotly-hover-and-click-events/833

I am having trouble binding the `plotly_click` event to my bar chart in plotly.js. From all of the documentation / posts I've seen (see links above), the data passed from the event to the callback should be structured like the following:

```
{
  points: [{
    curveNumber: 2,  // index in data of the trace associated with the selected point 
    pointNumber: 2,  // index of the selected point
    x: 5,        // x value
    y: 600,      // y value
    data: {/* */},       // ref to the trace as sent to Plotly.plot associated with the selected point
    fullData: {/* */},   // ref to the trace including all the defaults
   xaxis: {/* */},   // ref to x-axis object (i.e layout.xaxis) associated with the selected point
   yaxis: {/* */}    // ref to y-axis object " "
  }, {
    /* similarly for other selected points */
  }]
}
```

However, when my click event is triggered, I am see the following:

```
{
  currentTarget: div#containers-per-month-chart.js-plotly-plot
  data: undefined
  delegateTarget: div#containers-per-month-chart.js-plotly-plot
  handleObj: {type: "plotly_click", origType: "plotly_click", data: undefined, handler: ƒ, guid: 37, …}
  isTrigger: 3
  jQuery111208711647541870211: true
  namespace: ""
  namespace_re: null
  result: undefined
  target: div#containers-per-month-chart.js-plotly-plot
  timeStamp: 1572448651720
  type: "plotly_click"
  __proto__: Object
}
```

Does anybody know why the json I am receiving is different from what is documented? I am creating my chart and binding the click event as the document shows.

Here is how I am creating my chart:

```
Plotly.newPlot('my-plotly-bar-chart', data, layout, config);
```

Here is how I am binding the click event:

```
$('#my-plotly-bar-chart').on('plotly_click', function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                });
```

(I figured out my issue in the middle of writing this question, but in the spirit of [Self Answering to Document for others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) I figured I would still post the question and answer this myself.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `Plotly.js v1.50.1`

The issue is caused because the click event should be setup to accept two arguments in the callback function, not one as shown in the documentation.

As documented:

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');

// ... other setup here...

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
  // do some stuff
});
```

However, my solution looks like:

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');

// ... other setup here...

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(arg1,arg2){
  // do some stuff
});
```

`arg2` is the object we want, and looks like

```
{
    event: { ... }
    points: [
      {data: {…}, fullData: {…}, curveNumber: 0, pointNumber: 0, pointIndex: 0, …}
      {data: {…}, fullData: {…}, curveNumber: 1, pointNumber: 0, pointIndex: 0, …}
    ]

}
```

From there, we can extract the data from each point, which is as documented.

Comment: This helped me out. Interestingly, I had to use jquery too - using v 1.52.3

Comment: is my issue the same as above : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957122/plotly-onclick-event-cause-infinite-rendering-loop-in-react ?